# Firefox hanging on a ajax script/form serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have been playing with form serialization with ajax. I set this simple dice roller up. There two forms, one is the selector to select the dice and the next is a post back to post it back to a chat room.

IE runs fine with it.
Chrome runs fine with it, but firefox no matter what I do simply seems to hang. I'm not an expert on debugging with firefox. all I see is read code.jquery.com and then transferring data from... and that sit.

Some advise would be appreciated.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
var form=$("#diceRoller"); 
$( "#rollDice" ).click(function(event) {


$.ajax({

 type: "POST",

 url: "http://www.roleplayoasis.com/utils/dice.php",
 data: form.serialize(),
 success: function ( response ) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("diceInput"); // Get text field
    elem.value = response;
    $( "#roomPost" ).submit();
    return false;   
  }

});
});
});
</script>
```

There is a hidden diceInput variable in the roomPost form which is setup. As I said, it works fine in IE and Chrome, just won't work at all in Firefox.